# A InvalidArgumentError has been raised in keras when I build a simple model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My English is not good. If there is any inaccuracy in the description, please correct me.
here is error info:

> **ValueError**: Invalid reduction dimension 2 for input with 2 dimensions.
> for 'time_distributed_1/gru_1/Sum' (op: 'Sum') with input shapes:
> [?,8], [2] and with computed input tensors: input[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZecPU.png) = <1 2>.
>
> **InvalidArgumentError**: Invalid reduction dimension 2 for input with 2
> dimensions. for 'time_distributed_1/gru_1/Sum' (op: 'Sum') with input
> shapes: [?,8], [2] and with computed input tensors: input[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZecPU.png) = <1 2>.

here is full of code,I guess `input1 = Input(shape=(int(MAX_LEN//64),EMBEDDING_DIM,))` have some problems but I don't how to sovle it:

```
MAX_LEN = 512
NUM_FILTERS = 50
EMBEDDING_DIM = 200

input1 = Input(shape=(int(MAX_LEN//64),EMBEDDING_DIM,))
gru1 = GRU(NUM_FILTERS,recurrent_activation='sigmoid')(input1)
Encoder1 = Model(input1, gru1)
print("第1层构建完成。")

input2 = Input(shape=(8,int(MAX_LEN//64),))
embed2 = TimeDistributed(Encoder1)(input2)
gru2 = GRU(NUM_FILTERS,recurrent_activation='sigmoid')(embed2)
Encoder2 = Model(input2,gru2)
print("第2层构建完成。")

input3 = Input(shape=(8,8,int(MAX_LEN//64)))
embed3 = TimeDistributed(Encoder2)(input3)
gru3 = GRU(NUM_FILTERS,recurrent_activation='sigmoid')(embed3)
preds = Dense(5, activation='softmax')(gru3)
model = Model(input3, preds)
print("第3层构建完成。")
```

here is wrong code position: **embed2 = TimeDistributed(Encoder1)(input2)**

The frame of the model is shown in the picture below：

SRNN(8,2):
[image: SRNN(8,2)]

And this is `Encoder1.summary()`:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 8, 200)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
gru_1 (GRU)                  (None, 50)                37650     
=================================================================
Total params: 37,650
Trainable params: 37,650
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

This is my dataset file content format.The **[......]** Represents a vector of 200 dimensions:

```
[[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],]
[[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......]]
[[......],[......],[......],[......]]
[[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......]]
......
[[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......],[......]]
```

here is full of Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs)
   1566   try:
-> 1567     c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
   1568   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Invalid reduction dimension 2 for input with 2 dimensions. for 'time_distributed_1/gru_1/Sum' (op: 'Sum') with input shapes: [?,8], [2] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <1 2>.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-cfe569a6f2be> in <module>()
      1 input2 = Input(shape=(8,int(MAX_LEN//64),))
----> 2 embed2 = TimeDistributed(Encoder1)(input2)
      3 gru2 = GRU(NUM_FILTERS,recurrent_activation='sigmoid')(embed2)
      4 Encoder2 = Model(input2,gru2)
      5 print("第2层构建完成。")

E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    617 
    618             # Actually call the layer, collecting output(s), mask(s), and shape(s).
--> 619             output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
    620             output_mask = self.compute_mask(inputs, previous_mask)
    621 

E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\wrappers.py in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
    211             self._input_map[input_uid] = inputs
    212             # (num_samples * timesteps, ...)
--> 213             y = self.layer.call(inputs, **kwargs)
    214             if hasattr(y, '_uses_learning_phase'):
    215                 uses_learning_phase = y._uses_learning_phase

E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py in call(self, inputs, mask)
   2083             return self._output_tensor_cache[cache_key]
   2084         else:
-> 2085             output_tensors, _, _ = self.run_internal_graph(inputs, masks)
   2086             return output_tensors
   2087 

E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py in run_internal_graph(self, inputs, masks)
   2233                                 if 'mask' not in kwargs:
   2234                                     kwargs['mask'] = computed_mask
-> 2235                             output_tensors = _to_list(layer.call(computed_tensor, **kwargs))
   2236                             output_masks = layer.compute_mask(computed_tensor,
   2237                                                               computed_mask)

E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py in call(self, inputs, mask, training, initial_state)
   1587                                      mask=mask,
   1588                                      training=training,
-> 1589                                      initial_state=initial_state)
   1590 
   1591     @property

E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py in call(self, inputs, mask, training, initial_state, constants)
    558             initial_state = self.states
    559         else:
--> 560             initial_state = self.get_initial_state(inputs)
    561 
    562         if isinstance(mask, list):

E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py in get_initial_state(self, inputs)
    485         # build an all-zero tensor of shape (samples, output_dim)
    486         initial_state = K.zeros_like(inputs)  # (samples, timesteps, input_dim)
--> 487         initial_state = K.sum(initial_state, axis=(1, 2))  # (samples,)
    488         initial_state = K.expand_dims(initial_state)  # (samples, 1)
    489         if hasattr(self.cell.state_size, '__len__'):

E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in sum(x, axis, keepdims)
   1267         A tensor with sum of `x`.
   1268     """
-> 1269     return tf.reduce_sum(x, axis, keepdims)
   1270 
   1271 

E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    430                 'in a future version' if date is None else ('after %s' % date),
    431                 instructions)
--> 432       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    433     return tf_decorator.make_decorator(func, new_func, 'deprecated',
    434                                        _add_deprecated_arg_notice_to_docstring(

E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py in reduce_sum(input_tensor, axis, keepdims, name, reduction_indices, keep_dims)
   1421                                                   reduction_indices),
   1422                                    keepdims,
-> 1423                                    name=name))
   1424 
   1425 

E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py in _sum(input, axis, keep_dims, name)
   8655     _, _, _op = _op_def_lib._apply_op_helper(
   8656         "Sum", input=input, reduction_indices=axis, keep_dims=keep_dims,
-> 8657         name=name)
   8658     _result = _op.outputs[:]
   8659     _inputs_flat = _op.inputs

E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    785         op = g.create_op(op_type_name, inputs, output_types, name=scope,
    786                          input_types=input_types, attrs=attr_protos,
--> 787                          op_def=op_def)
    788       return output_structure, op_def.is_stateful, op
    789 

E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in create_op(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def, compute_shapes, compute_device)
   3390           input_types=input_types,
   3391           original_op=self._default_original_op,
-> 3392           op_def=op_def)
   3393 
   3394       # Note: shapes are lazily computed with the C API enabled.

E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in __init__(self, node_def, g, inputs, output_types, control_inputs, input_types, original_op, op_def)
   1732           op_def, inputs, node_def.attr)
   1733       self._c_op = _create_c_op(self._graph, node_def, grouped_inputs,
-> 1734                                 control_input_ops)
   1735     else:
   1736       self._c_op = None

E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs)
   1568   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
   1569     # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
-> 1570     raise ValueError(str(e))
   1571 
   1572   return c_op

ValueError: Invalid reduction dimension 2 for input with 2 dimensions. for 'time_distributed_1/gru_1/Sum' (op: 'Sum') with input shapes: [?,8], [2] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <1 2>.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can analysis the shape of every layer, and then you will find the following is right:

```
input1 = Input(shape=(MAX_LEN//64,200))
#embed = embedding_layer(input1)
gru1 = GRU(NUM_FILTERS,recurrent_activation='sigmoid',activation=None,return_sequences=False)(input1)
Encoder1 = Model(input1, gru1)

input2 = Input(shape=(8,MAX_LEN//64,200))
embed2 = TimeDistributed(Encoder1)(input2)
gru2 = GRU(NUM_FILTERS,recurrent_activation='sigmoid',activation=None,return_sequences=False)(embed2)
Encoder2 = Model(input2,gru2)
#
input3 = Input(shape=(8,8,MAX_LEN//64,200))
embed3 = TimeDistributed(Encoder2)(input3)
gru3 = GRU(NUM_FILTERS,recurrent_activation='sigmoid',activation=None,return_sequences=False)(embed3)
preds = Dense(5, activation='softmax')(gru3)
model = Model(input3, preds)

print(Encoder1.summary())
print(Encoder2.summary())
print(model.summary())
```